# sum over unique Weights of a job partition by sub id

Tags: sql, hana

I have a table having two IDS. The first product ID and the second job ID. Every job has different operations. Dach Operation has weight.

Example table:

```
ProductID| JobID     | OP  | weight    | 
---------+-----------+-----+-----------+
     1.  |     1.     | M.    |   0.   |
     1.  |     1.     | P.    |   1.   |
     1.  |     1.     | L.    |   3.   |
     1.  |     1.     | K.    |   0.   |
---------+------------+-------+--------+---- 
     1.  |     2.     | P.    |   1.   |
     1.  |     2.     | W.    |   0.   |
     1.  |     2.     | N.    |   2.   |
---------+------------+-------+--------+---- 
     1.  |     3.     | P.    |   1.   |
     1.  |     3.     | L.    |   3.   |
---------+------------+-------+--------+---- 
     1.  |     4.     | M.    |   0.   |
     1.  |     4.     | O.    |   1.   |
     1.  |     4.     | L.    |   0.   |
```

The need sums of the Wrights for OPs for every job, but the OPs done in previous job shouldnt be von considered in the second job.

Required Table

```
ProductID   | JobID | OP  | sum | 
------------+-------+-----+-----+
     1.     |     1.| M.  |   4.|
     1.     |     1.| P.  |   4.|
     1.     |     1.| L.  |   4.|
     1.     |     1.| K.  |   4.|
------------+-------+-----+-----+---- 
     1.     |     2.| P.  |   6.|
     1.     |     2.| W.  |   6.|
     1.     |     2.| N.  |   6.|
------------+-------+-----+-----+ 
     1.     |     3.| P.  |  9. |
     1.     |     3.| L.  |  9. |
------------+-------+-----+-----+ 
     1.     |     4.| M.  |  10.|
     1.     |     4.| O.  |  10.|
     1.     |     4.| L.  |  10.|
```

Once the Operation is done, their weigts shouldnt be considred in the next but the sum.

```
Sum(i)+sum(i+1)-sum(Weights of OPs previously done!)
```

I need help with the SQL logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a little hard to follow.  You seem to want a cumulative sum of the first OP value.  This cumulative sum is then "spread" through rows for a given jobid/weight.

You can do this with window functions.  The simplest method uses the `range between` windowing clause:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then weight else 0 end) over
           (order by productid, jobid
            range between unbounded preceding and current row
           ) as new_weight
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by op order by productid, jobid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Not all databases support `range between`.  Assuming that `weight` is never negative, you can just calculate the maximum value for each productid/jobid grouping:

```
select t.*, max(tmp_weight) over (partition by productid, jobid) as new_weight
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when seqnum = 1 then weight else 0 end) over
                 (order by productid, jobid) as tmp_weight
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by op order by productid, jobid) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! my Problem solved with `select t.*,
             sum(case when seqnum = 1 then weight else 0 end) over
                 (order by productid, jobid) as tmp_weight
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by op order by productid, jobid) as seqnum
            from t
`